# check if input is checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I achieve this:

```
if($(this).parent().find('input:checked') == true)

{$(this).find('.switch').attr('state','on');}
else{$(this).find('.switch').attr('state','off');}
```

I know this is wrong but you get the idea I think :). If there is an input that is checked add state on if not state off.

Comment: Could you show your markup and some more context for this code?  It's hard to know if the solution provided will be accurate from just this portion.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try with

```
if($(this).parent().find('input').is(':checked')) {
    something();
}
```

This works if there's only one checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessarily wrong, but the selector returns all elements that apply to the condition. Therefore you have to check if the length is not 0:

```
if($(this).parent().find('input:checked').length)
```

Answer (score 5):

Supposign `input[type=checkbox] = this`,  you can check it on the element itself.

Source: [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    if ( this.checked ){}
    //or
    if ( $(this).prop("checked") ){}   
    //or
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This also works if you know the id of the input html element:

```
if($('input#element_id_name:checked').length>0) {
  //your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the ID, just use:

```
if ($("#myCheckBox").is(":checked")) {  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
if ($(this).parent().find('input:checked').length > 0) {    
    $(this).find('.switch').attr('state','on');
} else {
    $(this).find('.switch').attr('state','off');
}
```

This assumes you have only 1 input within the scope of `$(this).parent()`